# three js geometry merge matrix

Tags: matrix, three.js

```
          var ShipGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

          var ShipModule1geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 150.0, 40, 30 );
              ShipGeometry.merge(ShipModule1geo); // this works

          var ShipModule2geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5.0, 5.0, 600, 1, 1, 1 );
          var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0,0,450);
              ShipGeometry.merge(ShipModule2geo,matrix); // this works too

          var ShipModule3geo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 150, 150, 20, 32 );
          var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, 850).makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2); 
              ShipGeometry.merge(ShipModule3geo,matrix); // only rotation is applyed 

          shipMesh = new THREE.Mesh( ShipGeometry, ShipMaterial ); 
          ....
```

My question, why  is applyed **only** `makeTranslation(0, 0, 850)`, **not** `makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2)` in last case?

**How to apply both before merging?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply both matrices like this:

```
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.multiply( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, 850) );
matrix.multiply( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2) );
```